# PhpStorm - how to display "connecting lines" between files and folders?

Tags: phpstorm

Some of JetBrains's IDE's have lines between the file and folders in the "Project" sidebar, which is helpful for showing the file folder hierarchy.

- Here is how my PhpStorm file explorer currently looks: [File Explorer](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/download/attachments/53332039/browse-remote-host.png?version=1&modificationDate=1393240677000)
- Here is how I want it to look: [File explorer sidebar with lines between files and folders](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/download/attachments/51183732/worddav6636609d058ca441441bda6a5d4bfe51.png?version=1&modificationDate=1363851670000)

*Note: I cant post image - not enough rep points.*

Is it possible to do this in PhpStorm? I'm using PhpStorm 8.0.3 on Ubuntu.

Comment: Show what you have got there. You can use http://postimage.org/ to upload images and then share the link.

Comment: If I understood you correctly -- generally speaking: this depends on GUI theme -- some themes provide such lines some do not. You may try different GUI theme at `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Appearance & Behaviour | Appearance --> Theme`.

Comment: @LazyOne thanks,  have provided a link to a screenshot showing an example of what I am trying to do, is it not working? I tried your suggestion about changing the themes - but the themes I have (PhpStorm 8.0.3) dont do it by default and I couldn't find any option to enable it within the themes feature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Such "lines" are part of the GUI Theme (also known as Look & Feel in Java applications).
2. You are using Darcula GUI Theme that does not support drawing such lines.
3. Your only option -- choose another GUI Theme at `Settings (Preferences on Mac) | Appearance & Behaviour | Appearance --> Theme`.

   Problem 1: It will be light theme as Darcula is the only one dark theme.

   Problem 2: I'm not sure if there is a theme for Linux version of PhpStorm that supports such lines (I'm a Windows user -- here "Windows" theme supports such lines). If there is none .. then you are out of luck...

Comment: thanks, yes I considered it may be a linux specific issue, the themes available to me are, **Darcula, GTK+, Alloy IDEA, IntelliJ** I tried those theme and their options and couldnt find anything

Comment: its worth noting that the themes I mentioned above apply to PhpStorm's **application** window. editable within `settings->appearance and behaviour->appearance`. There are lots of themes (e.g. Darcula) available for the **source code** itself - in `settings->editor->colors & fonts`

Answer (score 0):

In recents PhpStorm versions you can now use **Show tree indent guides** option

In:

> -> Settings
> -> Appearance & Behavior
> -> Appearance
> -> UI Options
> -> Show tree indent guides (checkbox)

[image: Show tree indent guides parameter screenshot]

Resulting something like that:

[image]